# In PowerShell how to compare Invoke-WebRequest content to a string

Tags: string, powershell, compare, invoke, webrequest

In my web page I create simple php script that on browser displays only my IP address as simple text in web page.

So if I use this command in PowerShell:

```
$ip = Invoke-WebRequest https://www.mypage.com
$ip
```

I get this result:

```
PS C:\Users\user> $ip
193.60.50.55
```

If I check what kind of variable is with: GetType().FullName I get:

```
PS C:\Users\user> $ip.GetType().FullName
System.String
```

And If I try to compare it with same string

```
PS C:\Users\user> $ip = Invoke-WebRequest https://www.mypage.com
$ip2 = "193.60.50.55"
$ip -eq $ip2
```

I get result "False", I also try with -match and -like but result is always false

Any Idea what is wrong

Comment: I a bit confused how `$ip = Invoke-WebRequest https://www.mypage.com` is only returning a single string, it should be returning an object with a ton of properties, can you post the result of `$ip | Get-Member`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mike Garuccio [points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40599027/in-powershell-how-to-compare-invoke-webrequest-content-to-a-string#comment68433924_40599027) `Invoke-WebRequest` returns object. You're seeing string because you've probably somehow triggered silent type conversion (using quotes, or having `$ip` declared as `[string]` before).

Example:

```
$ip = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://icanhazip.com/ -UseBasicParsing
"$ip"

1.2.3.4
```

-- or --

```
[string]$ip = ''
$ip = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://icanhazip.com/ -UseBasicParsing
$ip

1.2.3.4
```

This is what you should do:

```
# Get responce content as string
$ip = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://icanhazip.com/ -UseBasicParsing).Content

# Trim newlines and compare
$ip.Trim() -eq '1.2.3.4'
```

One-liner:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://icanhazip.com/ -UseBasicParsing).Content.Trim() -eq '1.2.3.4'
```